Type for heterogeneous *args
In typed Python, how do you type a *args list that you're expecting to pass to another argument that is a higher kinded function?
For example, this function takes a function and its first argument and internally just routes *args through, but its type signature depends on the type of that, possibly heterogeneous, argument list:
def curry_one[T, R](x: T, f: Callable[[T, WHAT_GOES_HERE], R]) -> Callable[[WHAT_GOES_HERE], R]:
  def curried(*args: WHAT_GOES_HERE) -> R:
    return f(x, *args)
  return curried

Can Expand be used with a generic type parameter over some kind of heterogeneous array?
(I'm not interested in a curry function in the standard library.  I'm writing some specific function adapters and am just using curry as an example.)

You are looking for TypeVarTuple, which represents an unknown number of types:
(playgrounds: Mypy, Pyright)
def curry_one[T, *Us, R](x: T, f: Callable[[T, *Us], R]) -> Callable[[*Us], R]:
  def curried(*args: *Us) -> R:
    return f(x, *args)
  return curried

def foo(a: int, b: str, c: float, d: bytes) -> None: ...

reveal_type(foo1 := curry_one(0, foo))      # (str, float, bytes) -> None
reveal_type(foo2 := curry_one('', foo1))    # (float, bytes) -> None
reveal_type(foo3 := curry_one(3.14, foo2))  # (bytes) -> None
reveal_type(foo4 := curry_one(b'', foo3))   # () -> None

Do note that all parameter names will be lost and thus arguments can only be passed positionally.
